# Component Instantiation vs Entity Instantiation in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have experience with Verilog/SystemVerilog but I am new to VHDL and I am trying to figure out when I should use component instantiation or entity instantiation.
By component instantiation I mean the legacy way of declaring components of an entity before instantiating them. On the other hand, entity instantiation, which has been introduced with [VHDL-93](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/compinst.html), allows you to declare an entity directly without specifying the component. 
[Related Article](http://www.fpga-dev.com/leaner-vhdl-with-entity-instantiation/)

It seems to me that Entity Instantiation is always preferable unless you don't have an architecture implemented yet and you just want to define a black box.

This is a [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641341/why-do-i-need-to-redeclare-vhdl-components-before-instantiating-them-in-other-ar) that I've found but it does fully address my doubts. Since it is possible to define both the generic map and the architecture for any entity:

```
entity work.MyEntity_E(ARCH) generic map(
...)
port map(
...
);
```

what is the additional flexibility of doing component instantiation? What would be the simplest example showing **something that can not be done with entity instantiation but can be done with component instantiation**?

Comment: With entity instantiation, you have to write the entity before you can compile this file... With a component, you can defer that step until you link (elaborate) the design.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant with "It seems to me that Entity Instantiation is always preferable unless you don't have an architecture implemented yet and you just want to define a black box". I realize now that sentence wasn't very clear. What are other benefits though? The articles I listed claim that the component instantiation approach is more flexible and I can't see why.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.8 Component declarations "A component declaration declares an interface to a virtual design entity that may be used in a component instantiation statement. A component configuration or a configuration specification can be used to associate a component instance with a design entity that resides in a library."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like to think of a *component* as being like an IC socket. You can take that analogy further by likening compilation (*analysis*) to assembling the PCB and likening *elaboration* to putting the chips in the sockets. If you use IC sockets, you can assemble the PCB even if you haven't ordered the chips yet; you can  defer putting the chips in the socket till later. Likewise if you use components: you can compile the design if even if the entities and architectures corresponding to the components don't yet exist; you can defer *binding* till later, till elaboration.

So, why might that be? Why might they not yet exist?

i) It's a big project. Not every one has finished their block yet. But you can still easily compile the top-level and run simulations on either bits of the design. You could do this by commenting-out/editing, but using components makes it easier.

ii) You've generated some IP automatically. This has given you a behavioural model for simulation, but no synthesisable model - the idea is that you combine some auto-generated physical view of the IP later in the flow. This is OK for simulation, but how can you compile your design for synthesis if there's a bit missing - your generated IP?

iii) You're doing recursive instantiation: you're instantiating one block inside itself. With *direct instantiation*, you've got an unbreakable chicken-and-egg situation (aka a *circular dependency*); with direct instantiation, you cannot instantiate something that has yet to be compiled, yet you cannot compile it, because the instantiated entity has not yet been compiled. *Component instantiation* can break this circular dependency.

iv) Component instantiation also enables you to instantiate different entities in the same place in your design (under the control of a *configuration*). @user1155120 gives an example of that above: using component instantiation (and a configuration) enables you to create identical blocks with differing sub-blocks.

Here's an example comparing the two on [EDA Playground - https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2QrS](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2QrS).

Comment: Re: iii, There's a distinction between analysis (objects in a library - compiling) and elaboration (linking and loading). You can't elaborate until meeting IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.5 Order of analysis "A primary unit whose name is referenced within a given design unit shall be analyzed prior to the analysis of the given design unit." In the case of a default binding indication, absent a configuration declaration (7.3.3) where a visible entity declaration doesn't meet analysis order. A configuration declaration (a primary unit) will similarly fail to elaborate. In analysis the issue is visibility.

Comment: @user1155120 I haven't thought about scenario iii). I can see how that could be used for sorting networks or similar. I am reading about configurations, do they have any equivalent in Verilog?

Comment: @igon Verilog does have configurations: [http://www.eda.org/sv-bc/hm/att-2972/ADV01_Configs_51_55.pdf](http://www.eda.org/sv-bc/hm/att-2972/ADV01_Configs_51_55.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

One of the things you can accomplish with configuration (which depends on component instantiation) is the use of virtual components.

You can write a VHDL description that depends on some idealized entity (named x here) and map it to different component with different port signal names:

```
entity a is
    port (
        in1:   in  bit;
        in2:   in  bit;
        out1:  out bit
    );
end entity;
architecture fum of a is
begin
    out1 <= in1 xor in2;
end architecture;

entity b is
end entity;

architecture foo of b is
    component x is
        port (
            a: in  bit;
            b: in  bit;
            c: out bit
        );
    end component;
    signal a, b, c: bit;
begin
TARG:
    x 
        port map (
            a => a,
            b => b,
            c => c
        );

STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        wait for 2 ns;
        a <= '1';
        wait for 2 ns;
        b <= '1';
        wait for 2 ns;
        a <= '0';
        wait for 2 ns;
        b <= '0';
        wait for 2 ns;
        a <= '1';
        wait for 2 ns;
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;

configuration fum of b is
    for foo
        for TARG: x use entity work.a
            port map (
                in1 => a,
                in2 => b,
                out1 => c
            );
        end for;
    end for;
end configuration fum;
```

elaborating and simulating the configuration gives:

[image: fum.png]

When looking a TARG's port signals.

This ability was intended to be used to map primitives from different vendor libraries to a standard component declaration.

The perceived complexity involved in configuration was countered with portability libraries such as LPM (Library of Parameterized Modules) which add a different axis of complexity via he use of attributes and generics while standardizing interface names and reducing the number of library primitives.

Behavioral synthesis has advance to the point both methods of structural design specification have fallen the way side.

FPGA vendor support for explicit configuration declarations has also historically lagged. You could note that IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, now withdrawn) required support for configuration declarations and implicit configuration provides default binding indications during elaboration.

Comment: +1 for showing that it's possible to use `port map` in a configuration. My VHDL designers didn't know this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

VHDL was originally a hardware documentation language. Not a simulation nor a synthesising one.

I agree that component instantiation is painfully verbose, but it's more readable in case the entity is not declared on the same source file.

Also, on really big projects. It allows to separate the compilation of each entity. So changing one entity doesn't mean recompiling the whole project.

And allows to easily swap with behavioral archs for simulation. Ie: a DRAM will just be a bunch of ports of your fpga. Or you may download a dram model and verify that your code is working as expected. You don't need to go back and change the instantiation each time you simulate something.

Comment: I understand the _supposed_ benefits in terms of readability and the compilation benefit. What is tripping me is that the [articles](http://www.fpga-dev.com/leaner-vhdl-with-entity-instantiation/) I linked mention component instantiation as more powerful because it allows you to **configure** the entity in more detail. What is something that I **can not do** with entity instantiation but I can with component instantiation?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/configurations_part_1/) about configurations

Comment: A [DES](https://www.dropbox.com/s/abjv929qo0kb90o/vhdl_des.tar.gz?dl=1) model using  configuration for 4 components identical except S Boxes (ROMs). Without component configuration it'd require four unique architectures, each uniquely instantiating two S boxes. Component configuration can enable more compact, easier to create or maintain descriptions and substitution of  specific components for virtual components. You can also map instantiated components (e.g. primitives) to different libraries and provide their generic and port maps in configuration specification binding indications.

Comment: "VHDL was originally a hardware documentation language." Can you supply a reference for this?

Comment: @user1155120 Can't remember where i first heard of it, but [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL#History) version matches.

Comment: And not a single substantial reference there. That wikipedia article also claims VHDL is a general purpose programming language which doesn't hold water, either.