# How to connect two modules in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I have two modules, mod1 and mod2. I want to connect mod1 to mod2 so the x1 and y1 inputs are the same as x2 and y2 inputs. So far I have done this but I don't know what to do next.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity modl is
    Port ( x1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           y1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           f1 : out  STD_LOGIC);
end modl;

architecture Behavioral of modl is


begin
    f1 <= NOT x1 and y1;

end Behavioral;


library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity mod2 is
    Port ( x2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           y2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              z2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           f2 : out  STD_LOGIC);
end mod2;

architecture Behavioral of mod2 is

    component mod1
    Port( x1 : in STD_LOGIC;
            y1 : in STD_LOGIC;
            f1 : out STD_LOGIC);
    end component;

    signal sign1: STD_LOGIC;


begin
    f2 <= x2 and y2 and z2;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to redeclare VHDL components before instantiating them in other architectures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641341/why-do-i-need-to-redeclare-vhdl-components-before-instantiating-them-in-other-ar)

Comment: Why don't you draw a picture of what you want to achieve?